# I want to identify if the device is an iPad on my project and created the below hook, But is not working in safari browser on iPad

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is the react hook I created to idenfify it:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { LANDSCAPE, PORTRAIT } from "../constants";

const useIPadOrientation = () => {
  const [isIPad, setIsIPad] = useState(false);
  const [screenDimensionOrientation, setScreenDimensionOrientation] =
    useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const updateDevice = () => {
      const isAnIpad =
        !!navigator?.userAgent?.match(/iPad/i) ||
        !!/iPad/.test(navigator?.platform);

      if (isAnIpad) {
        setIsIPad(true);
      } else {
        setIsIPad(false);
      }
    };

    const updateOrientation = () => {
      setScreenDimensionOrientation(
        window?.innerWidth > window?.innerHeight ? LANDSCAPE : PORTRAIT
      );
    };

    updateDevice();
    updateOrientation();
    window?.addEventListener("orientationchange", updateOrientation);
    window?.addEventListener("resize", updateDevice);

    const mediaQuery = window?.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)");
    mediaQuery?.addEventListener("change", updateOrientation);

    return () => {
      window?.removeEventListener("orientationchange", updateOrientation);
      window?.removeEventListener("resize", updateDevice);
      mediaQuery?.removeEventListener("change", updateOrientation);
    };
  }, []);

  return { isIPad, screenDimensionOrientation };
};

export default useIPadOrientation;
```

The isIPad property of this hook is working in chrome browser in iPad, however it is not working in Safari browser. I need help in fixing this for the Safari browser.